# In regex, how to search after the first occurrence of a string?

Tags: regex

Given I have a string

```
Teacher: ID: 123 Something: Something Name: ABC Age: 40 Student1: Name: XYZ Age: 12 Student2: Name: ABC
```

I want to check using regex that the first `Name:` after `Teacher` corresponds to `ABC`

I have tried to do using lazy

```
/(Teacher:(.*?)Name: ABC)
```

but that would return true even if

`Teacher: Name: EFG Age: 40 Student1: Name: XYZ Age: 12 Student2: Name: ABC` because it will then take the larger string.

EDIT: added try and made more generic

Comment: Why you do not search for `Teacher: Name:` and `Student2: Name: ABC`?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @Jens Because there might be more content between Name and Teacher

Comment: @D_action added in the question

Comment: what is it python or java? remove the unused tag.

Comment: when testing ypur expression it's seems correct! [link](https://regex101.com/r/GSTlze/1)

Answer (score 2):

You should not cross matching `Name:`

```
Teacher:(?:(?!\bName:).)*\bName: ABC
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ut89fU/1)